# ListView não aparece nas opções

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

No meu Eclipse, quando vou adicionar uma ListView, vejo um espaço vazio aonde ela deveria estar, fica como se fosse um botão, porém vazio e não é possível colocá-la na tela do App.  Talvez algum arquivo esteja corrompido, se for isso, teria como fazer uma verificação no Eclipse para analisar isso? 
EDIT: Acontece o seguinte, aonde fica o lugar da ListView, é um espaço em branco, creio que algum arquivo está corrompido, como faço com que o Eclipse analise os arquivo para verificar isso?

Comment: Fábio, tente colocar mais informações na sua pergunta.

Comment: Melhorei um pouco a pergunta

Comment: Coloque seu XML aqui